# JavaScript is not working in my below code

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have the below code written to Display TransactionList in JQGrid

```
<h2>Manage Transactions</h2>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#TransactionList").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            height: 150,
            colNames: ['TransactionID', 'MinVersion', 'TransactionDateTime','RequestMessage','ResponseMessage','TransactionName','TransactionDescription','Enabled'],
            colModel: [
              { name: 'TransactionID', index: 'TransactionID', width: 60 },
              { name: 'MinVersion', index: 'MinVersion', width: 100 },
              { name: 'TransactionDateTime', index: 'TransactionDateTime', width: 400 },
              { name: 'RequestMessage', index: 'RequestMessage', width: 60 },
              { name: 'ResponseMessage', index: 'ResponseMessage', width: 60 },
              { name: 'TransactionName', index: 'TransactionName', width: 60 },
              { name: 'TransactionDescription', index: 'TransactionDescription', width: 60 },
              { name: 'Enabled', index: 'Enabled', width: 60 }
        ],               
            multiselect: true,
            ignoreCase: true,
            hidegrid: False ,            
            pager: '#gridpager',
            rowNum: 10,
            viewrecords: true,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30, 400]    
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: 'API/GetTransaction',
            type: 'post',
            data: null,
            beforeSend: function () {
            },
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
                $("#TransactionList").setGridParam({ data: response }).trigger("reloadGrid");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
        $("#TransactionList").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn" });
    });
```

In the above code my javascript is not working. But,

```
<h2>Manage Transactions</h2>
```

Is printing on the Browser. Could any one help me with this?

Comment: Please post the whole html file (unless it has a lot of redundant information).

Comment: as pointed out in comments, first you should have table and div tags for jqgrid and pager. Second point, please use firebug, developer tools and look for error messages before posting any question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have no element with the id `TransactionList`.  Start by adding:

```
<div id="TransactionList"></div>
```

then work from there.

Comment: For the jqGrid to work the element will need to be a table, plus they need a div with the id of gridpager.

Comment: Ok, good point.  Never used it myself, but clearly there needs to be an element of some sort! :P